# Test around 90 sites with jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to test a list of sites with Jmeter.

I need to test a list of links from various sites using jmeter. The files are in a Excel column and I need to know their response time.

How do I accomplish this using jmeter?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to test only response time as single user or under load? If you want to see only response time of the sites as single user, then you can use gtmetrix.com

Comment: The response times you want to know, is that inclusive css, js, images and AJAX calls?

Comment: Have a look here: [asking](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/asking). You likely get down votes for [no research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/), [no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/) and [not trying](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). It seems like an homework question...

Answer (score 1):

1. Export your Excel file to CSV file, i.e. `urls.csv` and copy it to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Create an empty [JMeter Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan)
3. Add [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to your Test Plan and set "Loop Count" to `-1` (or tick "Forever" box)

   [image: JMeter Thread Group]
4. Add [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) inside the Thread Group and configure it as follows:

   [image: JMeter CSV Data Set Config]
5. Add [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to your Test Plan and configure it like:

   [image: JMeter HTTP]
6. Add [View Results in Table](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_in_Table) listener to your Test Plan and run your test. You should see URLs, response time, and few other metrics in the listener.

   [image: JMeter View Results Table]

Comment: Will that fetch images, css files, js files and perform AJAX calls?

Comment: No and no. For images, styles, scripts, fonts, etc. there is a checkbox [Retrieve All Embedded Resources from HTML Files](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses) at "Advanced" tab of the HTTP Request sampler. AJAX requests needs to be defined in the same (or another) CSV file and put under [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md).